# Using Ruby on Mac OS X, how to programmatically click on the screen -- and mouse move, mouse down, and mouse up?

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-snow-leopard, macruby, ruby-cocoa

What are the best way(s) to do it?  Can `ffi`, RubyCocoa, or MacRuby do it?

It seems like `CGEventCreateMouseEvent` or `CGPostMouseEvent` (deprecated) can be used.

Please give a working example.  thanks.

**Update:** the title of this question updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MacRuby your views can catch these events. Just look into the `DotView` example that comes with MacRuby.

```
class MyView < NSView 
  def mouseUp event
    puts convertPoint(event.locationInWindow, fromView:nil)
  end
end
```

Comment: sorry, I mean to write a program to click on a point on the screen

Comment: ah, okay. Luckily there's an example for this:
https://github.com/juanger/fvClicker/blob/master/WebClickerController.rb